# How to merge the result of a fetch into the master?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-fetch

I have just done a "cherry picking" by executing

```
git fetch ssh://myname@something1 something2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

After I execute `git branch` (to see what branch I am in), I see that I am in a branch with a strange name: `(HEAD detached at FETCH_HEAD)`:

```
* (HEAD detached at FETCH_HEAD)
  master
```

When I go to master by executing `git checkout master` this "strange" branch disappears and, as far as I understood, the changes that I "cherry picked" from the remote repository disappear as well (because they are in the "branch" that has disappeared).

So, my questions is: How can I merge the strange "branch" into the master so that the changes in this branch do not disappear?

Comment: You didn't cherry-pick anything at this point. the only thing you did was a branch hopping and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new branch (say, `b1`) from `FETCH_HEAD`:

```
$ git fetch ssh://myname@something1 something2 && git checkout -b b1 FETCH_HEAD
```

Push `b1` branch to remote, then create Pull request or pull `b1` into `master` directly.

```
$ git push origin b1
```

Pull `b1` branch into `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin b1
```

---

**Alternative:** If you simply want the remote repo changes into local `master` branch then:

```
$ git fetch ssh://myname@something1 something2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD

$ git checkout -b b1     # create b1 branch from FETCH_HEAD

$ git checkout master    # checkout to master
$ git merge b1           # merge b1 branch into master
```

Comment: Why do I need to push something to the remote branch? I just want to "take" something from the central repository. I do not contribute there at this point.